# Combining sum from 2 tables, and listing top 5

Tags: php, list

I know this has probably been asked 100 times, but I don't know the terminology to search for:
Please tell me how I can "select Top 5", or an equivalent, by combining a sum from 2 tables?

I need the top 5 results for "Money", where the "Money" is the combined sum of "Money" from the table named "wallet" and "Money" from the table named "bank", in this example.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I know you've probably heard this 100 times, but please post your table structure, some example data and show exactly what result set you want for your example data. It would also be useful if you could set up a working demo on http://sqlfiddle.com/ so that people can experiment with it.

Comment: Not enough to go on. As Mark says wed need the relevant parts of your schema from the tables involved and how you want to calculate "top 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use join after using sum

this is some examples

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
& another one
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html